# setting align_above in RelativeLayout not work programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to add a textView and ImageView at the bottom of the screen

I need to hide the textView and show it again programmatically

here I have this image to explain the Question and how the application should behave

the left rectangle desplays the TextView shown and the second for Hiding Textview:

[image]

I tried the code below to do that:

1- I added click listener to ImageView that hide the TextView and Change the LayoutParams of ImageView

2- On Clicking it again it will show the TextView and align the ImageView above it

> but the problem is that when I run the code the ImageView is stuck to
>   the top of the screen

I'm trying to change the LayoutParams of a view pragmatically using this code :

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv1 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/img" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignAbove="@id/tv1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the class MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv;
    ImageView image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);

        image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                //imageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

                imageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

                if(tv.getVisibility() == MyNavigationBar.GONE){
                    tv.setVisibility(MyNavigationBar.VISIBLE);


                    imageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.bottomNavigationBar);

                    image.setLayoutParams(imageParams);

                } else {
                    tv.setVisibility(MyNavigationBar.GONE);

                    imageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

                    image.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I think the problem is that the function :
imageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.bottomNavigationBar);

but its not work

I also tried to set an Id manually to the textView like:

```
tv.setId(1);
```

and changing the previous to :

```
imageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, tv1.getId());
```

Also doesn't work for me !!

I wonder that whether the problem in my code or in the android SDK !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems [layout_alignWithParentIfMissing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_alignWithParentIfMissing) would be much easier:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/img" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignAbove="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And only switch visibility of tv1 in your code:

```
image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(tv.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
            tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: just tried it...it stuck to the bottom of the screen now...what I want is to stuck to the bottom while the TextView is hidden and to stuck to the top of the Textview it its shown ... in that stat is stuck to the top also

Comment: In your onClick listener, only switch the visibility of R.id.tv1 (don't play with the layout param rules). With alignWithParentIfMissing, if the 'above' referenced view is GONE, it will align itself to the bottom of the screen

Comment: yes it does... but when the tv is Visible it also still in the bottom...not abot tv

Comment: try putting a + in the alignAbove, it shouldn't need it because the TextView is defined before the ImageView.. `android:layout_alignAbove="@+id/tv1"`

Comment: I got the same result... the image still stuck to the bottom

Comment: And your onClickListener looks like the one in the edit to the answer?

Comment: it works.... THANK YOU @FunkTheMonk ..........your code is great .... the problem was that after adding your code I forgot to delete .. tv1.setId(1);   when I deleted this line it worked.... THANK U ALOOOOOT